# Selecting from set of enum values

Tags: c#, linq, enums, lambda

I have collection of items which are having one enum property list.
Original property looks like

```
public class Content {
    List<State> States {get; set;}
}
```

where 'State' is enum with almost 15 options.

While iterating collection of Content objects, I want to check it States property has certain values like State.Important and State.Updated exists in States and set another string from it.

something like

```
if(item.States.Has(State.Important) && item.States.Has(State.Updated))
string toProcess = "Do";
```

How to do this using Linq or Lambda ?

Comment: This was just one example of If condition. I know "Contains". but used "Has" as example. I have so many if conditions base on combination of states. Some are even dynamic coming as another list<state> Thats why seeking for Linq or Lambda

Comment: I fail to see what it the problem with that. Just create a list of state for each condition, and apply any answer here with that. You could extend my answer, e.g, to easily manage a lot of cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work if you must use Linq:

```
if (item.States.Any(state => state == State.Important) && item.States.Any(state => state == State.Updated))
```

Otherwise just use `Contains()` like @ElRonnoco says.

(However if your states are flags (powers of 2), then this answer will be slightly different.)

The trouble with this approach is that it iterates over the collection fully twice if neither of the states are set. If this happens often, it will be slower than it could be.

You can solve it without linq in a single pass like so:

```
bool isUpdated = false;
bool isImportant = false;

foreach (var state in item.States)
{
    if (state == State.Important)
        isImportant = true;
    else if (state == State.Updated)
        isUpdated = true;

    if (isImportant && isUpdated)
        break;
}

if (isImportant && isUpdated)
{
    // ...
}
```

This is unlikely to be an issue unless you have very large lists which often don't have either of the target states set, so you're probably best off using El Ronnoco's solution anyway.

If you have a lot of states to deal with, you could simplify things by writing an extension method like so:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static bool AllPredicatesTrueOverall<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, params Predicate<T>[] predicates)
    {
        bool[] results = new bool[predicates.Length];

        foreach (var item in self)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < predicates.Length; ++i)
                if (predicates[i](item))
                    results[i] = true;

            if (results.All(state => state))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I had some difficulty coming up for a name for this. It will return `true` if for each predicate there is at least one item in the sequence for which the predicate is true. But that's a bit long for a method name... ;)

Then your example would become:

```
if (item.States.AllPredicatesTrueOverall(s => s == State.Important, s => s == State.Updated))
```

Here's some sample code that uses it:

```
enum State
{
    Unknown,
    Important,
    Updated,
    Deleted,
    Other
}

void run()
{
    IEnumerable<State> test1 = new[]
    {
        State.Important, 
        State.Updated, 
        State.Other, 
        State.Unknown
    };

    if (test1.AllPredicatesTrueOverall(s => s == State.Important, s => s == State.Updated))
        Console.WriteLine("test1 passes.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("test1 fails.");

    IEnumerable<State> test2 = new[]
    {
        State.Important, 
        State.Other, 
        State.Other, 
        State.Unknown
    };

    if (test2.AllPredicatesTrueOverall(s => s == State.Important, s => s == State.Updated))
        Console.WriteLine("test2 passes.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("test2 fails.");

    // And to show how you can use any number of predicates:

    bool result = test1.AllPredicatesTrueOverall
    (
        state => state == State.Important,
        state => state == State.Updated,
        state => state == State.Other,
        state => state == State.Deleted
    );
}
```

---

But perhaps the easiest is to write an extension method for `IEnumerable<State>` (if you only have the one state enum to worry about):

```
public static class EnumerableStateExt
{
    public static bool AllStatesSet(this IEnumerable<State> self, params State[] states)
    {
        bool[] results = new bool[states.Length];

        foreach (var item in self)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < states.Length; ++i)
                if (item == states[i])
                    results[i] = true;

            if (results.All(state => state))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then your original code will become:

```
if (item.States.AllStatesSet(State.Important, State.Updated))
```

and you can easily specify more states:

```
if (item.States.AllStatesSet(State.Important, State.Updated, State.Deleted))
```

Comment: +1 For mentioning flags - this sounds like a good approach for the OP perhaps. Rather than having a List of states, just have one state variable which itself can act as the list...

Comment: @PaoloTedesco Apologies - I misread the original question. However, I think my reading is finally correct!

Comment: writing combination of 15+ states using this way doesn't sounds good approach. I have so many if conditions base on combination of states. Some are even dynamic coming as another list<state> Thats why seeking for Linq or Lambda

Comment: @Nirav I've added some more examples.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Linq. I don't thinq

```
if(item.States.Contains(State.Important) && item.States.Contains(State.Updated))
  string toProcess = "Do";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Comment: I don't know if "thinq" is intentional, but please don't change it :)

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid it is intentional. I can't just throw that kind of comedy gold around by *accident*!!

Answer (score 1):

List has a `Contains` method, so your code would be

```
if(item.States.Contains(State.Important) && item.States.Contains(State.Updated))
    string toProcess = "Do";
```

I see no real benefit in using Linq or a lambda expression here...

Answer (score 0):

You could go with

```
!(new List<States>{State.Important, State.Updated}.Except(item.States).Any());
```

It's not really shorter, but easier if you have a huge number of states to check.

As long as you want to check that the item has all states needed, you just have to add new States to the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of following implementation

```
Content obj = new Content();
obj.States = SomeMethod(); 

if(obj.States.Any(h => h == State.Important) && obj.States.Any(h => h == State.Updated))
{
   string toProcess = "Do";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var res = (from items in item
                       where items.States.Has(State.Important) && items.States.Has(State.Updated)
                       select new { NewProcess = "Do" }).ToList();


foreach (var result in res)
    {
        string result = result.NewProcess
    }
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider using your enum as a *set of flags*, i.e. you can combine multiple states without having a list:

```
[Flags]
public enum State
{
    Important = 1,
    Updated = 2,
    Deleted = 4,
    XXX = 8
    ....
}

public class Content
{
    public State MyState { get; set; }
}

if ((myContent.MyState & State.Important) == State.Important
    && (myContent.MyState & State.Updated) == State.Updated)
{
    // Important AND updated
}
```